# "Blank item at the end of listbox"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2007. I just started to learn some vba to improve my spreadsheets. When populating a listbox with an array, an empty blank space appears at the bottom of the list.

If I populate the listbox with a range from a spreadsheet, everything seems ok. But when using an array, a blank item is added at the bottom. So when I set the ListStyle to 1, an additional option button or check box with a blank space is at the bottom of the list. Is there a way to fix this?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim myArray(5) As String

    myArray(0) = "January"
    myArray(1) = "February"
    myArray(2) = "March"
    myArray(3) = "April"
    myArray(4) = "May"

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "60"
        .List = myArray
    End With

    With ListBox2
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "60"
        .List = Range("Months").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [show relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you post some of the code you use to set the ListBox source range?

Comment: First guess is you populate a specific range, e.g., `arr = range(cells(1,1),cells(10,1)) // .list = arr`, and the last few are blanks as opposed to your selecting `.list = range(cells(1,1),cells(7,1))`.

Comment: I'm using a test form, so I don't mess the real one. The form has two list boxes. the ListBox1 adds the empty row. ListBox2 do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim myArray(5) As String
```

That does not create an array with 5 items; it creates an array with an implicit lower bound of `0`, and an explicit **upper bound** of `5`, making the array hold 6 items...

```
myArray(0) = "January"
myArray(1) = "February"
myArray(2) = "March"
myArray(3) = "April"
myArray(4) = "May"
```

...with the last one left with its default initial value, an empty string.

Declare explicit lower *and* upper bounds:

```
Dim myArray(0 To 4) As String
```

And the "blank item at the bottom" should disappear.

Comment: And another thanks for clarifying lower and upper bounds. I wasn't very clear with those concepts yet.

Comment: @quique19 awesome! Feel free to mark this answer as "accepted", by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons, near the top of this answer.